# @client.event excludes other commands discord bot python

Tags: python, discord.py

This `@client.event` excludes other commands!!! Pls help me!
`async def on_message(message): if client.user.mention in message.content.split(): await message.channel.send('xyz')` 
This is my code: (Without the @client.event it works corectly, but when I add other @client.event, rest of the code doesnt works, only client.event works. Guys help!!!

````
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('xyz ~ {0.user}'.format(client))
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Piwo?"))



  

@client.command()
@has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, reason="Za darmo lamusie"):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"***xyz***")


@client.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, reason="Za darmo lamusie"):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"***{member.mention} xyz ***")




@client.command()
async def jaka_gierka(ctx):
    gierki = [xyz]
    await ctx.channel.send(random.choice(gierki))


@client.command()
async def graj(ctx, game):
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=game))

@client.command()
async def streamuj(ctx, game):
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name=game, url="xyz"))



@client.command()
async def sluchaj(ctx, music):
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name=music))


@client.command()
async def ogladaj(ctx, film):
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=film))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if client.user.mention in message.content.split():
      await message.channel.send('xyz')



client.run("token")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [process commands in `on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=process_commands#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands).

Without doing this, none of the commands will execute. The default behavior was to have an `on_message` that only processed commands. However, you made a custom event handler, so this must be done manually. You can change your `on_message` to this:

On an unrelated note, checking for the `<@1234>` mention sequence in the message is a bad idea. Instead, you can use [`mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.mentions).

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user in message.mentions:  # checks if the bot was in the list of people mentioned
        await message.channel.send('xyz')
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Please [flag as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) instead of posting a duplicate answer